# How to list remote contract/freelance work on a resume?

Tags: resume, telecommute, contracting

Typically, one would list a workplace on their resume with location included, eg.:

```
Widget Producer, XYZ Corp, San Francisco, CA May 2010-February 2011
```

How should remote freelance/contract positions be listed when the client company was located in a different place than the contractor?

BONUS: since it's me asking, note also that my own location has changed during the course of the contracting, making listing my location inaccurate.

Comment: Is there something horribly wrong with *"Off-Site Widget Producer, XYZ Corp, San Francisco, CA May 2010-February 2011"*? Or *"Widget Producer, XYZ Corp, Off-site Contractor May 2010-February 2011"*? And is there any definitive answer to this question?

Comment: I don't think there's a definitive answer to this, but if I were working full-time remotely (contractor or otherwise), I would use: _Widget Producer, XYZ Corp, San Francisco CA (remote), May 2010 - Feb 2011_.

Comment: This question is how do I list frelance/remote work for a company on my resume.  This seems quite in our wheelhouse of acceptable questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Typically, one would list a workplace on their resume with location
>   included, eg.:
>
> Widget Producer, XYZ Corp, San Francisco, CA May 2010-February 2011
>
> How should remote freelance/contract positions be listed when the
>   client company was located in a different place than the contractor?

You are listing the location of the company, not the location of where you were sitting when you performed the work.

Thus, I would suggest that you simply continue to list it something like this:

> Widget Producer, XYZ Corp, San Francisco, CA May 2010-February 2011
>
> Senior Developer (contract)

During the interview, it may lead into a discussion about your working remotely.

At some point, if you intend to work remotely in your next job, you want to make that clear with the interviewers. For some companies, that works well, for others, they would want you to be local. You don't want to have any confusion about that point during the interview process.