# How to list company location on resume if you don't have a "home office"

Tags: resume, consulting

I've worked for several years for a consulting firm (as a full-time salaried employee), but never exactly had a "home office" that I was based out of. Two of their offices are near-ish but I still never went in to them because they're a long drive and I was almost always at client sites around the globe anyway.

So what I'm struggling with is how to list that on a resume/application that requires a location and phone number for my employer. Do I just pick one of the closer offices? Do I put the corporate headquarters? Do I list my home address since that's where I worked when not on-site?

I do know that [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/790/how-to-list-contracting-on-resume) may also be the answer, but since I was a salaried employee, even when not working for a client, I'm not sure if it applies here. Also in that case I'm not technically allowed to disclose clients on paper, only in person.

Comment: Seems to me that in this case you should put your home address, as it is where you actually work from.

Comment: Don't overthink. There's no wrong answer. If I were you, in my resume, I would put the company name and corp address. As this is the address of my company. During the interview, I'll explain to them my situation and I'm mostly on client sites.

Comment: Does your boss work out of an office? If so, then put that address down.

Comment: why not put your company's hq address

Comment: My only concern about putting the HQ down is that when I do interviews, without fail, the people I'm talking to don't understand the fact that I don't have an office. They ask questions like "Well where do your paychecks come from?" or "Where does your W2 say you work?" I don't carry a W2 in my back pocket, and I'm pretty sure it says where the billing department is anyways.

Comment: @Michael Due to the nature of consulting firms, no one has a "boss" in the traditional sense. You have project managers, which are temporary, regional managers, who you don't directly report to, and career advisors, who are the closest thing to a boss but they don't actually *manage* you, just advise and give feedback. It's fairly nebulous. Also he/she would probably work from home as well.

Comment: @thanby So who writes your annual reviews? I think you should put the address on your W-2. In todays market, people do work remote so it’s not that big of a deal. I think you are over thinking this.

Comment: @Isaiah3015 That's sounding like the most sound advice so far. But then the issue becomes that the people who interview me don't understand why I live on one coast and work on the other, which has made more than one HR representative to tell me they almost threw out my resume because it didn't make sense.

Comment: @Michael Reviews are done by peers at the end of a contract and by multiple people higher up the chain in my region, and that's all pooled together and discussed by the regional board twice per year. Unfortunately that provides zero clarity. You're probably right about me overthinking it, but I don't see a distinct answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to list remote contract/freelance work on a resume?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/15474/how-to-list-remote-contract-freelance-work-on-a-resume)

Comment: @thanby If you get the interview, then you can just explain it as you have here.  As for possibly making it clear in your resume, see the linked answer.  If they give you a fixed form that doesn't let you make it clear, I don't know what to say.

Comment: @thanby I don't know why the HR wouldn't understand. I've interviewed people for my company(LA) where the guy had an LA address but his employment history was in Canada (current) and his  (previous) England, +France. Took me 5 seconds to realize he works remote. I conducted the initial interview while he was in Canada. He explained his employment history and it's pretty easy to understand. It would really baffle me if someone don't get that.

Answer (score 8):

I never put addresses on resumes.  I put cities.  I've never had a case in 30 years where someone wanted the address from my resume. They'll want it on background checks and when you're filling out applications perhaps but that's another story altogether.

Another reason is that addresses are just more information they're not going to look at in the 30 seconds that they're deciding whether to put your resume in the call-back pile or the no-thanks pile. Only put things on your resume that will help them decide whether they want to call you for an interview. The city should be location enough for that without giving them something they have to ignore.

Comment: The question also asked about applications, and those sometimes do require an address.  It doesn't make that much sense, but a lot of application questions don't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Indeed, many companies have their own proprietary systems for submitting resumes, which involve uploading the resume and then re-typing all the information that their web service mangled in trying to interpret it. Then they ask you additional questions, like location, that are irrelevant in the long run. But regardless, you must comply because of the stupid "required" tag in the ASP form.

Comment: Agreed on this. I think it's important to note the reason why to even include the city of a company on a resume is mainly so that when researching your history, the interviewer can distinguish your ABC Corp in Toledo from a different ABC Corp in San Francisco.

Comment: @thanby lol at the "ASP form".  You are so right. It seems that companies who require these things seem to be stuck in the last century.

Answer (score 2):

You put whatever address they can use to verify that company exists and that you worked there.  They don't care and want what's on your W-2 because that's what they want the address for, employment verification, they don't want to go there and sift through your leavings. The HQ address should be fine for that purpose.

You claim that HR people have gotten confused about an office being in one place and you working in another, but if you say "consultant, travel" I find that super unlikely and if it's true they are demented to the point you can probably safely pass them by.

Comment: That may be one indicator of a bad apple, but it's not always the case. I've found that people who have never done consulting have a hard time wrapping their head around exactly how it works, there's more misconception out there than fact, from my experience